# proguard exception while creating apk in ecllipse in android

Tags: android, proguard

In my application i want to enable  proguard for that i added proguard.config=proguard.cfg
in project.properties.

My proguard.cfg contains

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.*
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>; }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); }

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); }

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {    public void *(android.view.View); }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *; }
```

My console:

```
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.io.Buffer
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.Address
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.io.Buffer
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.Address
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields$Field
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.JettyOAuthConsumer: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: there were 31 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
    please help me how to solve this issue
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988163/1318946

Answer (score 1):

You didn't added settings for twitter4j in proguard.  You should add below settings

```
-dontwarn javax.management.**
-dontwarn java.lang.management.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.json.*
```

and this:

```
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
```

This will solve your issue

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply i added your code but still i am getting errors

Comment: Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.client.HttpExchange
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.jetty.HttpRequestAdapter: can't find referenced class org.mortbay.jetty.HttpFields  Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
[2013-06-06 18:32:00 - Explosionfilters] Warning: oauth.signpost.signature.OAuthMessageSigner: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Comment: i edited my post i am using signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar,signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar,signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jartwitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar, these are jars which are i am using how to add them in proguard.cfg

Comment: use like `-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }` for all external jars. replace `twitter4j` for topmost package name for each jars

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31332/discussion-between-user1083266-and-pankaj-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, but my issue has been solved by adding following lines to my 'proguard-android.txt' file.

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-dontwarn org.mortbay.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**

-keep class twitter4j.** { *; }
```

For Google play services like Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.content.pm.PackageInstaller

This is the solution! Hope it works for you too!